# Как запретить закрытие окна при клике за его пределами?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую стандартное модальное окно jQuery

```
var $modal = $('#event-modal');
var modal_body = $(".modal-body");
var modal_content = $(".modal-content");

function mcloced (a) {
    $modal.find('.modal-body').empty().end();
    $modal.removeClass(a);
}   
function addok (a) {
    $modal.removeClass(a);
}   

$('.give-transfer').on('click', function () {

    var id_cabinet = $(this).data('id-cabinet'); 
    var id_data = $(this).data('id-data'); 
    var id_staff = $(this).data('id-staff'); 
    var id_staff_old = $(this).data('id-staff-old'); 
    var vid = $(this).data('vid'); 
    var http_referer = $(this).data('http-referer'); 
    /* 
    var id_staff_appoint = $('#id_staff_appoint').val(); */

    $modal.modal('show');
    //$modal.modal({backdrop: false});

    addclassmodal = 'modal-transfer';

    $modal.addClass(addclassmodal);

    $modal.find('.modal-body').empty().end();

    $(".load-modal").addClass('active');

    document.getElementById('action').value = "transfer";

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/selects.php?vid=transfer&action=" + vid + "&id_cabinet="+ id_cabinet,
            data: "id_staff=",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $(".load-modal").removeClass('active');
                if(data.succes == 0){
                    jQuery('#msgbox_staff').html('' + data.msg + '');
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $("#msgbox_staff").html('');
                    },10000);
                }
                if(data.succes == 1) {

                    $('.modal-title').html(''+ data.title_modal +'');

                    modal_body.append(''+ data.content_modal +'');


                    $('.js-transfer-lead').on('click', function () {

                        var email_transfer_checked = $("#email_transfer").is(':checked');
                        var sms_transfer = $("#sms_transfer").is(':checked');
                        var telegram_transfer = $("#telegram_transfer").is(':checked');
                        var info = $("#info").is(':checked');

                        var TransferParam = {
                            id_data: id_data,
                            id_staff_new: $('#id_staff_new').val(),
                            vid: $('#vid').val(),
                            email_transfer: email_transfer_checked,
                            id_staff_old: id_staff_old,
                            id_staff: id_staff,
                            id_cabinet: id_cabinet,
                            sms_transfer: sms_transfer,
                            telegram_transfer: telegram_transfer,
                            info: info
                        };
                        // отправляем данные на сервер
                        $.post('/update_status.php?vid=transfer', TransferParam, 
                            function(data){
                                if(data.succes == 0){ 
                                    $("#msgbox_transfer").html("" + data.msg + "");
                                        setTimeout(function(){
                                            $("#msgbox_transfer").html('');
                                        },10000);
                                }  
                                if(data.succes == 1){
                                    $("#msgbox_transfer").html("" + data.msg + ""); 
                                        setTimeout(function(){
                                            $("#msgbox_transfer").html('');
                                            location.href = http_referer; 
                                        },2000);
                                }
                            }, "json");

                            return false;
                    });

                }
            }
        });

    $('.close-modal').bind('click', function () {
        mcloced (addclassmodal);
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function (e){ // событие клика по веб-документу

        if (!modal_content.is(e.target) // если клик был не по нашему блоку
            && modal_content.has(e.target).length === 0) { // и не по его дочерним элементам
            $modal.find('.modal-body').empty().end();
            mcloced(addclassmodal);
        }
    }); 

});
```

Как этому окну запретить закрываться если клик сделан за пределами `.modal-body`, т.е чтобы окно закрывалось только при нажатии на крестик?

Comment: Я Вас возможно расстрою, но в библиотеке jQuery нет стандартного модального окна.

Comment: что за код приведен в вопросе? Убираешь в нем последний обработчик mouseup - и ничего не будет закрываться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читайте [документацию](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp)
Свойство `backdrop` (`data-backdrop`):

> If you specify the value "static", it is not possible to close the modal when clicking outside of it

Что в переводе на русский обозначает,

> Если вы укажите значение `static`, то будет  невозможно закрыть модальное окно при клике вне его области.

Comment: Однако вы телепат...

Comment: повесил весь код, как сделать правильно, просто попробовал что-то все равно закрывает.

Comment: А как bootstrap modal относится к коду в вопросе?

Comment: все решил проблему спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

самый простой вариант это задать стиль для подложки `pointer-events: none;`